# Regression for scattering kernel (physics)

Tags: regression, machine-learning

In my kinetic theory research (physics), I encounter the modelling of the scattering kernel $B(X,X')$ via the relation

$f(X)=\int B(X,X')f'(X')dX'$

where $X$ and $X'$ are random variables with distribution $f$ and $f'$. We can say that the above equation connects the distribution of input $X'$ and output $X$. I already have the data $(X,X')$ and want to model $B(X,X')$ or at least predict the distribution of $X$ for some special distribution of $X'$. In this case, which regression models or machine learning algorithms are recommended to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

Given knowledge of $B(X,X')$, the problem of predicting the distribution of $X$ given observed information $X'$ is referred to as deconvolution or "unfolding." If you are willing to give up a parametric model for the kernel $B(X,X')$, known as the "response matrix" in the deconvolution literature, your problem can be approached through popular unfolding/deconvolution tools. For example, the popular  [RooUnfold](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/software/unfold/RooUnfold.html) tool can take the distributions of $X$ and $X'$ and estimate $B(X,X')$ (using one of several methods, such as matrix inversion, [SVD decomposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9509307), or [Bayesian methods](http://inspirehep.net/record/374574)). These non-parametric approaches generally require binning the data $X$ and $X'$. The resulting estimate can be applied to new data.